# How to correctly setup DataContractSerializer()?

Tags: c#

```
public string Serialize(BackgroundJobInfo info)
{
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(BackgroundJobInfo),
                     null, int.MaxValue, true, true, new MongoDbSurrogate());
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter(stringBuilder, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter);
        serializer.WriteObject(writer, info);
        writer.Flush();
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

That's how I created my `serializer`

```
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(BackgroundJobInfo), null,
 int.MaxValue, true, true, new MongoDbSurrogate()); // MongoDbSurrogate: IDataContractSurrogate
```

After that I started to have the following exceptions:

An exception of type `System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException`

`Type System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection 1[[Replay.Common.Contracts.Transfer.ExcludedWriter, Common.Contracts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] with data contract name ArrayOfExcludedWriter:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Replay.Common.Contracts.Transfer' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer.`

I already added 6 `[KnownType(typeof(some_type_in_exception))]` to `BackgroundJobInfo`. And I still get the same exceptions with different types.

Maybe I did something wrong(for example second parameter in constructor (known types) must be different than `null`)? How can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 0):

> I already added 6 [KnownType(typeof(some_type_in_exception))] to BackgroundJobInfo. And I still get the same exceptions with different types.

Your solution is working. You just haven't found all. There is no magical way to find them all, you are the programmer, you are supposed to know what types are used. You will have to continue to find them all.

Comment: Why I get this exceptions? Can you explain please?

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko You get those exceptions because those types cannot be inferred at compile time. This happens for example if your return type is an interface. You need to have all *implementations* of that interface that you *actually return* as known types because the compiler cannot get them from the method signature.